# How can I iterate this object and apply a function to the inner values of p1 and p2 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

javascript code to iterate nested object and apply an encryption function on its values

encryption is my own function which is working fine but i am not able to iterate it and make a new object from it

```
"credentials": {
        "p1":{
            "twilio_account_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_api_secret":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_api_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_auth_token":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_number":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_twiml_app_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9"
        },
        "p2":{
            "twilio_account_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_api_secret":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_api_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_auth_token":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_number":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_twiml_app_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9"
        }
    }
```

```
 for(provider in credentials){
          encObj[provider] = credentials[provider]
          for(key in credentials[provider] ) {
            provider.key = encryption(credentials[provider][key])
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ovewrite the key on the `encObj` object

```js
const credentials = {
        "p1":{
            "twilio_account_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_api_secret":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_api_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_auth_token":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_number":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_twiml_app_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9"
        },
        "p2":{
            "twilio_account_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_api_secret":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_api_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_auth_token":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_number":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9",
            "twilio_twiml_app_sid":"318192y892ejfdhauiwy89ey28we9"
        }
    }
    
 const encryption = (text) => `changed${text}`;

 let encObj={};
 for(provider in credentials){
          encObj[provider] = { ...credentials[provider]};
          for(key in credentials[provider] ) {
            encObj[provider][key] = encryption(credentials[provider][key])
          }
        }

console.log(encObj);
```

Comment: Are you sure that this will work? Seems like `encObj[provider] = credentials[provider]` will copy the reference of the object, so you will probably operate on the same object and also change the input variable `credentials`.

Comment: You are right. Fixed. Thank you ;)